# Update TextView without Freezing Application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, android-asynctask

I'm reading **Sensor Data** from Device Sensors(**Multiple Sensors**) and call a Method to show the data I received from sensors to the designed TextView.

The method I'm calling to update TextView:

```
private void UpdateDataStream(String _Entry,Boolean isAppend)
{
    if(isAppend)
        ViewHolder.append("\n("+sensorName+")"+_Entry);
    else
        ViewHolder.setText("("+sensorName+")"+_Entry);
}
```

Method called from **SensorEventListener's** , **onSensorChanged** Event.

What I couldn't figure out is how to prevent freeze while updating TextView; since sensor data update is intensive(considering it is from multiple sensors simultaneously) updating TextView cause Application to freeze or crash. **I don't need to "print" every data I received, like It is enough for me to print for every 1-2 second, lost data can be ignored.**

Is there any approach/patern or built-in structure to achieve this ? 
(I'm new to programming in Java&Android, yet I'm familiar with multiprogramming, parallel programming concepts, yet I couldn't figure out how to apply them in this environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fastest solution:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html

Or you can:

- create stack (for example)
- write sensors data stream to stack from `thread#1`
- in another infinite loop `thread#2` read last data from stack every **N** time (don't forget to synchronize them)
- clean the stack
- write last data to TextView (don't forget to set text in ui thread: `textView.post( () -> textView.setText("safe call") );`